# Navigation taking time

Tags: ios

I am navigating by clicking a button to a viewcontroller where I am loading webview,but after clicking the button it is taking some time,how to navigate faster and load webview faster,please help.I have only the following code in second viewcontroller.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl"]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.wb loadRequest:request] ;

        });
    });           
}
```

Comment: What is in your viewDidLoad

Comment: Nothing - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    
   
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);

    // execute a task on that queue asynchronously
    dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl"]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.wb loadRequest:request] ;

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Nikos,I tried this code but same performence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, there isn't much you can do to make if faster. That request speed is based on internet speed (Over which you don't have much of a control).

Also the request already happens asynchronously, so there's no need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are combining two things as you navigate to your webview

1. loading and displaying a view
2. Retrieving data from the internet

You can only directly influence the first one, the second one is well beyond your control.

By performing the asynchronous NSURLRequest from within the `viewWillAppear` method, you are telling iOS to delay showing the view until the internet has given you all the data it needs.

A better approach is to configure all the visual elements of your new view, display that view in the interface, and then AFTER the new view is visible, perform your NSURLRequest.

Adding a UIActivityIndicator may also help your users realize that your app was snappy and responsive, and the delay they are experiencing is from the internet.

Perhaps the easiest way to fix this would be to move your code over to

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {}
```